# Our app is not compliant with Google Play Policies

Tags: android, google-play

[image]Issue found: Invalid Data safety form

We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 3: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)

I tried to update the information in Data safety but still, have the same error.
SPLIT_BUNDLE 3: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about an application store's policy, which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/11107541) for more information.